# Web API WorkBook download

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a Workbook using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. My problem is this will be a API call and currently it works but saves to the server. Is there a way to have it download straight to the client and avoid server side saving. I used a memory stream for a csv but that will not support what I need and now need to use excel.

```
Workbook workbook = new Application().Workbooks.Add();
                var mySheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];
                var lastRow = mySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row;
                foreach (var tempResult in violationsResults)
                {
                    lastRow += 1;
                    mySheet.Cells[lastRow, 01] = tempResult.InfractionDate;
                    mySheet.Cells[lastRow, 02] = tempResult.ProductName;
                    mySheet.Cells[lastRow, 03] = tempResult.Sku;
                    mySheet.Cells[lastRow, 04] = tempResult.ProductLine;
                    mySheet.Cells[lastRow, 05] = tempResult.MappPrice;
                    mySheet.Cells[lastRow, 06] = tempResult.AdvertisedPrice;
                    mySheet.Cells[lastRow, 07] = tempResult.Difference;
                    mySheet.Cells[lastRow, 08] = tempResult.SellerDomain;
                    mySheet.Cells[lastRow, 09] = tempResult.Merchant;
                    mySheet.Cells[lastRow, 10] = tempResult.Upc;
                    mySheet.Cells[lastRow, 11] = tempResult.DomainSku;
                    mySheet.Cells[lastRow, 12] = tempResult.Fba;
                    mySheet.Cells[lastRow, 13] = tempResult.Mvid;
                }

                workbook.SaveAs("C:\\Temp\\hello_excel.xlsx");
```

Comment: Using office interop in a server-side app is a *very* bad idea.  Look into one of the many .net libraries for creating native excel files. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a file from your temp folder and make your download, or use a MemoryStream to store your file and then download.

```
public void DownloadWorkbook(string filePath)
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
    HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;

    response.ClearContent();

    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
    response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());       
    response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
    response.End();
}
```

Hope it helps.